# Using NOT EXISTS with a subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, not-exists

I'm trying to create a query to retrieve all customers who purchased one SKU ('Red399') but did not also purchase a second SKU ('Red323'). It seems like the best way to do this is by using `NOT EXISTS` with a subquery to filter out people who bought 'Red323'.

My query isn't returning any errors, but it also isn't returning any results, and I think it might be because I have too many conditions in the initial `WHERE` clause but I'm not sure:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT o."FirstName", o."LastName", o."Email", ol."SKU"
FROM flight_export_order o
JOIN flight_export_orderline ol
    ON o."OrderDisplayID" = ol."OrderDisplayID"
WHERE ol."SKU" = 'Red399'
AND o."OrderDate" BETWEEN '07/22/2020' AND '08/03/2020'
AND NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT DISTINCT o."Email" 
    FROM flight_export_order o
    JOIN flight_export_orderline ol
        ON o."OrderDisplayID" = ol."OrderDisplayID"
    WHERE ol."SKU" = 'Red323'
    AND o."OrderDate" BETWEEN '07/22/2020' AND '08/03/2020')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the subquery.
You can group by customer and set the conditions in the `having` clause:

```
SELECT o."FirstName", o."LastName", o."Email"
FROM flight_export_order o INNER JOIN flight_export_orderline ol
ON o."OrderDisplayID" = ol."OrderDisplayID"
WHERE ol."SKU" IN ('Red399', 'Red323')
  AND o."OrderDate" BETWEEN '07/22/2020' AND '08/03/2020'
GROUP BY o."FirstName", o."LastName", o."Email"
HAVING SUM((ol."SKU" = 'Red399')::int) > 0
   AND SUM((ol."SKU" = 'Red323')::int) = 0
```

Comment: Thank you, this works! Just to clarify so I understand why this works- you are getting the numbers of each bottle purchased by casting the SKU as an int, correct?

Comment: For example: the boolean expression `ol."SKU" = 'Red399'` is casted to an int: 0 or 1 for false and true. So by summing these 0s and 1s if you get a number > 0 then there was a purchase of `'Red399'`.

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track to begin with. `EXISTS` / `NOT EXISTS` are the right tools:

```sql
SELECT o.* --  or just the columns you need
FROM   flight_export_order o
WHERE  o."OrderDate" BETWEEN '2020-07-22' AND '2020-08-03'
AND    EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM flight_export_orderline
   WHERE  "OrderDisplayID" = o."OrderDisplayID"
   AND    "SKU" = 'Red399'
   )
AND    NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM flight_export_orderline
   WHERE  "OrderDisplayID" = o."OrderDisplayID"
   AND    "SKU" = 'Red323'
   );
```

With a multicolumn **index** on `flight_export_orderline ("OrderDisplayID", "SKU")`, this is as fast as it gets. An index on just `("OrderDisplayID")` (like you probably have) goes a long way, too.

Plus an index on `flight_export_order("OrderDate")`, obviously.

I see no need for any expensive aggregating or `DISTINCT`. See:

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)

Aside 1: try to avoid quoted CaMeL-case identifiers in Postgres if you can. See:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)

Aside 2: It's [reommended to use ISO 8601 date format](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-DATE-TABLE) (`YYYY-MM-DD`), which is always unambiguous and independent of locale and session settings.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation!